# POST API body values coming through undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, authentication, postman

I am building up an API on the MEAN stack, using mongoose. The API should handle user signup and authentication. To test this, I am using the chrome extension, postman to submit post requests to `/signup`.

```
app.use("/signup", bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));    
app.post("/signup", Auth.userExist, function (req, res, next) {
             if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
                    res.json({success: false, msg: 'Please pass name and password.'});
                    console.log("email: " + req.body.email);
                    console.log("password: " + req.body.password);
                } else {
                    //do create new user logic...
                    res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user.'});
                }
});
```

Here you can see what I am sending in the body of my request to the API:

[image: Postman]

in the console, I am getting this:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Why is the body of my request not getting through?

Comment: Can you show how did you import User model to controller?

Comment: @BibekSubedi `var User = require ('../api/public/user/model/userModel');` at the top

Comment: Is the save callback executing?  Is the user being saved to the db?  Have you tried UserSchema.insert() instead of save()?

Comment: @tronman I don't think so. Although, not sure if it is failing because the password hasn't been hashed, or if it isn't being attempted. I just get the error back and not triggering of the pre-method. Also, insert doesn't make a difference

Comment: @tronman please see the updated question showing the error message returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **POSTMAN** select `x-www-form-urlencoded`instead of `form` and then pass the form values. Your code should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring body parser for your endpoint:

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use("/signup", bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: hmmm, if I do that I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined" - I just put app.use directly above my app.post in the routes class and the require at the top.